# BindingSource: How cancel changes to current item

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, c#-4.0, bindingsource

I've got list of items which I get from repository_DohvatiSveZapise:

```
      using Entities entities = new Entities())
        {
            return entities.Zapis.ToList();
        }
```

and that list I use as datasource

```
      this.zapisBindingSource.DataSource = baza.DohvatiSveZapise();
```

Object "Zapis" has some string properties which are bound to textboxes. When user change value in some textboxe, he can choose to save or discard changes. I tried this for discarding

```
  zapisBindingSource.CancelEdit();
```

but current item (bindingsource.Current which is modified by user) has still modified values. How can I undo all changes made to current item in binding source?

Comment: What happens if you try setting the binding source `this.zapisBindingSource.DataSource = baza.DohvatiSveZapise();` again?

Comment: Then it works..but it means I'm reading from database for example 1000 records just to undo changes made on one of them....

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic management for canceling modifications of custom objects.

From the [BindingSource.CancelEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.canceledit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) MSDN page :

> This method discards modifications to data since the last save or load
>   operation if both of the following conditions are met:
>
> - The data source
>     implements the IEditableObject interface.
> - The EndEdit method has not
>     been called yet.

So you need to code your own cancellation logic in implementing the IEditableObject interface.